# Homogenous Containers with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

Let's say I have two tables.  One for containers of fruit, and one for the fruit.  Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Containers
(
ContainerID int,
ContainedFruit int
)

CREATE TABLE Fruit
(
FruitID int,
Name VARCHAR(16)
)

INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 1, 'Apple' )
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 2, 'Banana' )
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 3, 'Cherry' )
INSERT INTO FRUIT VALUES ( 4, 'Date' )

INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 101, 1 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 101, 1 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 102, 1 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 102, 2 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 102, 3 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 103, 3 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 103, 4 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 104, 3 )
```

I want to find all container ID's that have only one TYPE of fruit in them.  They're allowed to have two apples in them (as in the case of container 101), or just 1 item in them (container 104).  But containers 102 and 103 have two different kinds of fruit in them so I don't want them to be included.

How would I do a SELECT that would grab containers 101 and 104, and any other containers in the future that only have one type of fruit in them?

--EDIT--

OK, so that's actually just half my question:

Let's say I've got a third table.  That uniquely identifies the container.  It's kinda implied in this structure anyway:

```
INSERT INTO FRUIT VALUES ( 0, 'Mixed' )

CREATE TABLE Each_Container
(
Container ID int PRIMARY KEY,
FruitType int
)

INSERT INTO Each_Container VALUES ( 101, 0 )
INSERT INTO Each_Container VALUES ( 102, 0 )
INSERT INTO Each_Container VALUES ( 103, 0 )
INSERT INTO Each_Container VALUES ( 104, 3 )
```

Now at this point, the first three containers are marked as MIXED.  Whilst the fourth is just a container for cherries.  But here's my question:

How do I UPDATE all the ERRONEOUSLY marked containers like 101?  The ones that are only marked MIXED because they've got multiple fruit in them even though they're the same type of fruit?  102 and 103 SHOULD be mixed, but 101 shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an aggregation and `having` clause:

```
select ContainerId
from Containers
group by ContainerId
having count(distinct ContainedFruit) = 1
```

A slightly more efficient form of this is:

```
select ContainerId
from Containers
group by ContainerId
having min(ContainedFruit) = max(ContainedFruit)
```

Also, your data structure is missing a table.  The table called `Containers` should really be `ContainerFruit` because it "joins" the contains and fruit.  There should be a separate table called `Containers` that has one row per container.

Comment: `min(ContainedFruit) = max(ContainedFruit)` is a very nice trick

Comment: Catcall - Yeah, you're right.  I've edited the the question because this actually becomes a larger one, whereby I want to update the missing (I called it Each_Container) table.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT ContainerID
FROM Cointainers
GROUP BY ContainerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ContainedFruit) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from (select ContainerID, count(distinct ContainedFruit) num_types
      from Containers
      group by ContainerID) t
where num_types = 1
```